# Group column value to sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a below data:

```
User    Group
user1   G1
user1   G2
user1   G3
user1   G7
user2   G10
user2   G4
user2   G7
user2   G1
user2   G13
user3   G16
user3   G5
user3   G6
user4   G2
user4   G13
user4   G15
user4   G10
```

I want to prepare associated data in the below format:

```
       G1  G2 G3 G4 G5 G6 G7 G10 G13 G15 G16
user1  1   1  1  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0  
user2  1   0  0  1  0  0  1  1   1   0   0
user3  0   0  0  0  1  1  0  0   1   0   1
user4  0   1  0  0  0  0  0  1   1   1   0
```

I tried transposing every user separately, but that did not helped me.
Is there any way to do this job, as I have much bigger data. I know it will create a parse matrix but that is what I wanted to create.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In complement to the other answer, you can use natural sorting with `natsort`:

```py
from natsort import natsorted
df2 = pd.crosstab(df['User'], df['Group'])
df2[natsorted(df2.columns)]
```

output:

```
Group  G1  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6  G7  G10  G13  G15  G16
User                                                 
user1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1    0    0    0    0
user2   1   0   0   1   0   0   1    1    1    0    0
user3   0   0   0   0   1   1   0    0    0    0    1
user4   0   1   0   0   0   0   0    1    1    1    0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pandas.crosstab` and pass the index and columns parameters

```py
>>> pd.crosstab(df['User'], df['Group'])

Group  G1  G10  G13  G15  G16  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6  G7
User                                                 
user1   1    0    0    0    0   1   1   0   0   0   1
user2   1    1    1    0    0   0   0   1   0   0   1
user3   0    0    0    0    1   0   0   0   1   1   0
user4   0    1    1    1    0   1   0   0   0   0   0
```

If you want the columns to appear in sorted fashion as you have in the expected output, you can just sort the columns later, after the `crosstab` (sorting the `Group` column of the initial dataframe will also work, but it will have performance impact):

```py
>>> out = pd.crosstab(df['User'], df['Group'])
>>> out[sorted(out.columns, key= lambda x: int(''.join(i for i in x if i.isdigit())))]

Group  G1  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6  G7  G10  G13  G15  G16
User                                                 
user1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1    0    0    0    0
user2   1   0   0   1   0   0   1    1    1    0    0
user3   0   0   0   0   1   1   0    0    0    0    1
user4   0   1   0   0   0   0   0    1    1    1    0
```

Comment: I added a complement to your answer. Python has a builtin module for natural sorting ;) +1